# Problem with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Does anybody have any idea why this doesn't work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var loading;
    var results;

    form = document.getElementById('form');
    loading = document.getElementById('loading');
    results = document.getElementById('results');

    $('#Submit').click( function() {

        if($('#Search').val() == "Desired name here..")
        {alert('Please enter a valid domain name, Thank you.');return false;}

        results.style.display = 'none';
        $('#results').html('');
        $("#loading").fadeIn(2000);

        $.post('process.php?domain=' + escape($('#Search').val()),{
        }, function(response){

            results.style.display = 'block';
            $('#results').html(unescape(response)); 
            loading.style.display = 'none';
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="Submit"><img src="img/submit_domain.png" height="30" width="73" class="host_sb"></a>
```

I have jQuery installed, and it works in every other browser.

**This is my problem:**

Nothing loads. The #loading doesn't show which in turn doesn't display the #results

Comment: In what way does it not work? Does it give an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: Define "doesn't work" - what happens, what were you expecting to happen and what have you tried so far to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, should have been a little more descriptive. Nothing loads. The #loading doesn't show which in turn doesn't display the #results.

Comment: sory but just copy-paste code and telling it doesnt work is not enough :-) try to debug in Developer toolbar or Firebug first to see what part doesnt work...

Comment: Are you using any other JavaScript libraries in the page besides jQuery?

Comment: Nothing else, just jQuery and it's UI.

Comment: Why are you using `getElementById` and `style.display` when you can just use jQuery and `.hide()`?

Comment: Please post the full code and tell us, what `process.php` does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is weird mix of plain JavaScript and jQuery.. not sure this cause the problem but try this optimized version:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Submit').click(function() {
        var searchValue = $('#Search').val();
        if (searchValue === "Desired name here..") {
            alert('Please enter a valid domain name, Thank you.');
            return false;
        }

        var oResults = $('#results');
        oResults.html('');
        oResults.hide();
        $("#loading").fadeIn(2000);

        var now = new Date();
        $.post('process.php?domain=' + encodeURIComponent(searchValue) + '&t=' + now.getTime() , { }, function(response) {
            oResults.show();
            oResults.html(decodeURIComponent(response)); 
            $("#loading").hide();
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

If no luck, try debug if you don't have any tools use plain old alert - add `alert('got here');` in key lines like the beginning of the `.click()` function or the AJAX callback.